# trigonometric identity of sin squared in terms of tan squared.

Tags: trigonometry

Why is $\sin^2(x)=\frac{\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}$? And why is $\sin^2(x)=\frac{1}{\cot^2(x)}$?

I've tried starting from $\tan^2(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}$ but that wasn't really working out for me.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please add parentheses. I don't think the second equation is an identity.

Comment: If the second one is $$\;\sin^2x=\frac1{\cot^2x}=\tan^2x$$ then it is definitely false.

Comment: In fact, you can prove the first identity by assuming that $\tan^2 (x) = \sin^2(x) / (1-\sin^2(x))$, as you have stated. Let $t = \tan^2 x$ and $s = \sin^2 x$, rearrange and solve for $s$. Of course, the method in Timbuc's answer is far better.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

$$\frac{\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}=\frac{\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}}{1+\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}}=\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}=\sin^2x$$

Now you try the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2x=\frac{1}{\csc^2x}=\frac{\frac{1}{\csc^2x}}{1}\cdot\frac{\sec^2 x}{\sec^2 x}=\frac{(\frac{\sec x}{\csc x})^2}{\sec^2 x}=\frac{\tan^2 x}{\tan^2+1}$$

Now all that's left to prove is that $\tan x = \dfrac{\sec x}{\csc x}$
$$\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{\frac{1}{\csc x}}{\frac{1}{\sec x}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\csc x}}{\frac{1}{\sec x}}\cdot\frac{\frac{\sec x\csc x}{1}}{\frac{\sec x\csc x}{1}}=\frac{\sec x}{\csc x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the identity $\tan^2x + 1 = \sec^2x$ yields

\begin{align*}
\frac{\tan^2x}{1 + \tan^2x} & = \frac{\tan^2x}{\sec^2x}\\
                            & = \tan^2x\cos^2x\\
                            & = \frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x} \cdot \cos^2x\\
                            & = \sin^2x
\end{align*}